# How to get the sales order delivery address from openerp using PHP

Tags: php, odoo

I want to get the sales order delivery address from openerp. Below is the process I am using but unfortunately I am getting invoice address instead of deliver address. Please let me know the way so that I can get the delivery address.

I am getting sales order by using below queries

```
$arr[]='manual';
$arr[]='shipping_except';
$arr[]='done';
$arr[]='progress';

$partner_ids = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
    'sale.order', 'search',array(array(array('state', 'in', $arr),array('date_order', '=', '2018-04-11')))
        );
$saledata=$models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
     'sale.order', 'read',
     array($partner_ids)
    );
```

After that to get the delivery address I am using below code

```
$userspecificdata=$models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
      'res.partner', 'read',
      array($sales['partner_invoice_id'][0])
      );
```

and using below fileds to get the delivery address but unfortunately I am getting invoice address

```
"street1"=>$userspecificdata["street"],
"city"=>$userspecificdata["city"],
"state"=>$userspecificdata["state_id"]["1"],
"zip"=>$userspecificdata["zip"],
"country"=>$userspecificdata["country"]["1"],
"phone"=>$userspecificdata["phone"],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'partner_shipping_id' instead of 'partner_invoice_id'

Comment: Thanks for valuable answer.